# How to copy file with varying number after the first 4 characters in file name?

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch file that when run will look into a specific folder in `Program Files (86)` and copy and paste that file into another folder. Now I already know the code thanks to this website.

Here is my dilemma: the file changes from computer to computer. I know the first 4 letters are `xxxx` then followed by an unknown amount of numbers.

Can I make a .bat file that could look for the beginning of a file name?

Comment: What about using simply wildcard `*` to copy all files starting with `xxxx`, i.e. `copy "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Source Folder\xxx*" "C:\Target Folder\"`? This simple command line does not check if the copied file has more than `xxxx` in file name and all those additional characters are digits in range of 0 to 9. But perhaps there is only 1 file starting with `xxxx` in the source folder and additional file name checking mechanisms are not needed at all. Your question is too broad for knowing that.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\abcd*" '
 ) DO (
 SET "name=%%~na"
 SET "name=9!name:~4!"
 FOR /L %%z IN (0,1,9) DO SET "name=!name:%%z=!"
 IF NOT DEFINED name ECHO(COPY "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

The required COPY commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(COPY` to `COPY` to actually copy the files. Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file copied`)

after setting `delayedexpansion` mode, perform a directory scan of the source directory, in `/b` basic mode `/a-d` without directories and assign each filename found to `%%a`.

set `name` fom the name part only of `%%a`, then remove the first 4 characters and include a `9` into the modified name.

Then remove all `0` to `9` from the result, and if `name` becomes empty, do the copy. Note that the `9` is added so that the string `name` remains non-empty until the very last iteration of the `for /L` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\program files (x86)"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "xxxx*"^|findstr /i "\\xxxx[0-9][0-9]*\."') DO (
  ECHO copy "%%a" "c:\another folder\"
)
popd
```

(NOTE: the `copy` command is disabled by an `ECHO`. Remove the `ECHO`, if the output looks correct.)

filter the output of the `dir` command to find:
- `\\` a literal `\` followed by
- `xxxx` the known prefix followed by
- `[0-9]` at least one number followed by
- `[0-9]*` zero or more numbers followed by
- `\.`  a literal `.`

Pro's: no delayed expansion needed, should be (slightly) faster than Magoo's solution

To look also into subfolders, add `/s` to the `dir` command.